# Error when I delete a node from a linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have:

```
class Node {
   int* vec;
   Node* next;
};

Class LinkedList{
   Node* head;
}
```

I made a function that found the node that I want to delete:

```
Node* tmp = find("abc");
```

I ordered the pointers and I debug it and everything is OK.

now I have to delete the `tmp`, so I tried:

```
delete[] tmp->vec;
delete tmp; // here I get an error window.
```

why?

**THIS IS MY REAL CODE:**

```
class Show_Time
{
  private:
    string movieCode;
    string movieName;
    string time; //the time of screening the movie.
};


class Time_LinkedList
{
 private:
    class Time_Node
    {
     public:
        Show_Time* data;
        Time_Node* prev;
        Time_Node* next;
     public:
        Time_Node(string movie_code, string movie_name, string time_of_movie); //"Time_Node" constructor
        ~Time_Node();//"Time_Node" destructor
    };
    Time_Node* head; //pointer to the first node in the linkedlist
};


void Time_LinkedList::delete_TimeNode(string movieCode, string time)
{
    Time_Node* tmp = find_Time_Node(movieCode,time);

    // the case that there is one element in the list
    if (tmp->prev == NULL && tmp->next == NULL)
    {
        head = NULL;
    }

    // the case that it's the first element of the list
    else if (tmp->prev == NULL)
    {
        head = tmp->next;
        tmp->next->prev = head;        
    }

    // the case that it's the last element of the list
    else if (tmp->next == NULL)
    {
        tmp->prev->next = NULL;
    }

    // there are element in the left and right of the element
    else
    {
        tmp->prev->next = tmp->next;
        tmp->next->prev = tmp->prev;
    }

    // delete the temp and its data
    delete tmp->data;
    delete tmp;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the code where you allocate `vec`

Comment: There can be plenty of reasons. You're going to need to show us some more code !

Comment: ok, I'm updating my topic for the real code. thank you.

Comment: @AlonShmiel Ok, I see the update but there is code missing where is the constructor and destructor? Is the destructor doing `delete data`?

Comment: yes:
Time_LinkedList::Time_Node::~Time_Node()
{
    delete data;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So according to your response your issue is that you are doing a `double delete` which is [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9169774/what-happens-in-a-double-delete). You should remove the `delete data` from `Time_LinkedList::delete_TimeNode` and let the destructor do it's job.