# new and delete Memory Management out of scope

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks, new-operator

```
void f(const Fraction& a)
{ Fraction b = a;
  Fraction* c = new Fraction(3, 4);
  Fraction* d = &a;
  Fraction* e = new Fraction(7, 8);
  Fraction* f = c;
  delete f;
 }
```

1. Which values do I delete?
   I think I only delete c which is dynamically allocated and rest of the objects are destroyed automatically when the function ends.
2. How about e? It is also dynamically allocated but we don't have any delete operator for e.  The e is not de-allocated?

Thanks,

Comment: `delete` doesn't delete a variable. It deletes allocated memory which a pointer variable points to.

Comment: You have two `new`s and one `delete`. You are leaking  one `Fraction`.

Comment: I guess the third line is not even possible. You are pointing at a const object with a (non-const) pointer.

Comment: A more essential question: why are you dynamically allocating `Fraction`, when it manifestedly supports copy and assignment?

Comment: Yeah that was my mistake. I was trying to find which values are deleted and which objects are deleted as well. THanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key insight which you're probably missing here is that `delete` does not have any relationship with a specific *variable* - it has a relationship with a specific *object* stored at a certain *memory address*.  It's commonly stated as a rule that "any object allocated with `new` must be deallocated with `delete`."  But note the use of the word ***object*** - not variable.

Consider:

```
Fraction* a = new Fraction(3,4);
Fraction* b = a;
delete b;
```

In this example we deleted `b`, which points to the `Fraction` object allocated on the first line.  We also could have deleted `a`, which pointed to the same `Fraction` object.  As long as we delete every ***object*** allocated with `new` (regardless of which pointer variable we use to access the object), there is no memory leak.  Also note that if we delete *both* `a` and `b` then we have an error (undefined behavior via a [double-delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9169774/what-happens-in-a-double-delete)).

Answer (score 4):

You should delete `c` (or `f`), but not both and you should delete `e`. For each `new` should be `delete`.

Comment: But he could just as easily delete `e` and `f`.  (In fact, he already deletes `f`.)

Answer (score 1):

1. You will delete object created with `new Fraction(3, 4);`
2. Yes `e` or more strictly saying memory allocated with `new Fraction(7, 8);`  will not be deallocated leading to memory leak.

Answer (score 1):

You should delete (c or f) & e