# how to pass a scoped pointer rather than a this pointer?

Tags: c++, qt

I have two classes. In the class `A` constructor, I am calling the constructor of class `B`. However, while creating class `B` object, I want to pass the QSCOPED pointer of the class `A` object. In short, instead of this pointer, I want to pass the QSCOPED pointer. How can I do so?

```
class B;
class A
{

 class A();

};

A::A()
{
  QScopedPointer<B> m_p_B( new B(this));
}
```

My requirement is that instead of passing `this` pointer, I want to pass the QSCOPED pointer of the class `A`. Basically a QSCOPED pointer of `this` pointer. How can I do so?

Comment: please paste a definition of B class

Comment: You say you want to pass the QSCOPED pointer of the class `A` object - does that mean that the instance of `A` was created as a `QScopedPointer`? (That is, was the instance represented by `this` created by `QScopedPointer<A>(new A())`?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

It's not needed to pass `QScopedPointer` in the constructor, it will be created in the initializer list.

```
#include<QScopedPointer>

class B
{
public:
    B(A* a) : ma(a) {}

private:
    QScopedPointer<A> ma;
}
```

Comment: This could be a really dangerous move, since we don't have any knowledge of who "owns" the `A` resource. 1) If the instance was created via `new`, then this is ok (if the owner doesn't call `delete`); 2) If the instance was created via `new`, but already wrapped in a `QScopedPointer`, then this will result in a [double delete](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9169774/what-happens-in-a-double-delete "Question: What happens in a double delete?"); 3) If the instance was created on the stack, this will lead to undefined behavior

Comment: @Lilshieste you're right, I have totally ignored this side of the story. I assumed that if there is a request to wrap A in a scoped pointer all these 1) 2) 3) are taken care of.