# How can I avoid double deleting variables in c++?

Tags: c++, memory-management, delete-operator

I have read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9169774/what-happens-in-a-double-delete), as well as elsewhere, that deleting the same variable twice can be disastrous (even when there is more than one variable name).

Suppose I have a function which takes an input and output array:

```
void test(int*& input, int*& output) {
  if(input[0] == 0) {
    output = input;
  }
}
```

and it may assign a pointer to another variable I'm using:

```
int *input = new int[3];
int *output = new int[3];

input[0] = 0;

test(input, output);

delete[] input;
delete[] output;
```

how can I avoid the double delete?

In this overly simplified scenario, I know I could check the pointer addresses to see if they are equal and conditionally only delete one of them, but is there a better solution when I won't know pointers might be pointing to the same memory?

**Edit:**

tidied up the things to avoid some confusion..

Comment: *"how can I avoid the double delete?"* This isn't snarky, so don't read it as such - [don't use `new`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500313/).

Comment: And don't use `delete` either

Comment: Your code does not have a double delete anyway, `input` and `output` point to different buffers.  The local variables of the same names inside `test` do not affect variables outside the function.

Comment: @DrewDormann in that answer, it describes using the stack instead of the heap. I was using ```new``` for passing a blank array to an initializer list for a struct (inline). Is there a way to get a new stack-based array with the initializer list syntax? Or should I just declare a variable?

Comment: "passing a blank array to an initializer list for a struct (inline)" - huh? It would help to post the code you are trying to describe.

Comment: Did you mean to make the parameters to `test` be `(int*& input, int*& output)`? As RSahu pointed out, your code does not suffer from a "double delete". The double delete requires pointers passed by reference or pointers to  pointers.

Comment: @MattMcNabb I didn't want to confuse the issue too much, but a struct like ```foo {int *array; int someVar}``` and function takes a foo as ```test({new int[5], 42});```

Comment: @Derek no, I was trying to keep it simple, but in the real code, the references are to structs, so the local shadowing is not an issue. I feel I've muddied the waters... but I'm learning a lot!

Comment: @snapfractalpop that would be an extremely bad struct design

Comment: @MattMcNabb bad because it has a variable size array with no size variable?

Comment: @snapfractalpop because it is unclear who manages the memory for `array`. (which is a ponter, not an array). Anything with raw pointers, new, or delete is suspect.

Comment: @MattMcNabb any advice on where to read up more?

Comment: `output = input;` does not do what you think it does.

Comment: @immibis in theory, this means that every time I think it does something, it has to do something else. I can't imagine everything that it can do, but I can imagine imagining everything it can do. So, then I think it must do nothing, forcing it to do something, and restarting the loop. Surely it does one thing: confuses the whole thread. One stroke of carelessness in the name of simplicity.. and brain == fried.

Comment: @snapfractalpop It doesn't do what you thought it did when you wrote it <- fixed? Hint: the `test` function doesn't do anything, besides waste a few nanoseconds.

Comment: @immibis I knew that when I wrote it.. and was careless anyway because I didn't consider it important for the underlying question. In reality, the code has a function that takes structs, and only part of the referenced output struct is reassigned to the input part. Basically, to avoid confusion, I caused more confusion. I hope it's clear enough now with this comment, and the one replying to Derek.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally speaking the best way to avoid double delete is to not allocate memory directly with `new`. There are various smart pointers you can use like `scoped_ptr` and `shared_ptr`, and in your case you can use `std::Vector`:

```
typedef std::vector<int> Ints;

void test(const Ints& input, Ints& output)
{
  if(input[0] == 0) {
    output = input;
  }
}

Ints input(3);
Ints output(3);

input[0] = 0;

test(input, output);
```

Comment: `input[0] = 0;` and the following line need to be in a function

Answer (score 7):

The way to avoid double deletes is to design your code so that the ownership of objects is well defined.  There can only be one owner of an object at a time, though ownership can be passed from one owning entity to another. An object owner can be a piece of code (such as a function) or a data structure.  When the owner is done with an object, it is the owner's responsibility to either pass ownership to something else or to destroy the object.