# Why one of those two similar functions crashes and one works ok?

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

This is really weird. If I increase the value of `asize` just by one `crashSystem()` does what its name speaks. Second function returning an int pointer works ok with much bigger values. Those two functions just delete and allocate the same dynamic array with same size (I created it just for test purposes).

Note: I think it could have something to do with maximum stack capacity 1MB (130037 * 8 in bytes is near 1MB), but it's really strange 'cause allocating using `new` inside function should work the same as any other `new`.

Using Visual Studio 2015

```
#include <iostream>

void crashSystem(int * dynamicArray, int asize) {
    delete[] dynamicArray;
    //dynamicArray = nullptr; does not matter at all
    dynamicArray = new int[asize];
    std::cout << "mem allocated\n";
}

int * worksOk(int * dynamicArray, int asize) {
    int * newDynamicArray = new int[asize];
    delete[] dynamicArray;
    std::cout << "mem allocated\n";
    return newDynamicArray;
}

int main()
{
    int asize = 130037; // dynamic array size
    //asize = 12330037; // for testing second function that works
    int * dynamicArray;

    dynamicArray = new int[asize];

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "iteration " << i << " ";
        crashSystem(dynamicArray, asize);
        //dynamicArray = worksOk(dynamicArray, asize);
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Note 2: Crashing app this way in Release mode tends to block executable by creating non existent process (checked with Process Hacker 2)

Comment: I presume that worksOK only worksOK if you write `dynamicArray = worksOK(...)` right?

Comment: I only tested it this way, I mean as a return function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you're passing pointer by value, so it still points to the `new int[asize];` allocated in `main()`, on which you then [call multiple `delete []`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9169774/what-happens-in-a-double-delete).
It becomes a [dangling pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17997228/what-is-a-dangling-pointer) after the first `delete []` call.

Even assigning `nullptr` won't help you if the pointer is not being passed by reference.

`worksOk` works, because you're returning the pointer pointing to the newly allocated space and assigning it, so it's valid every time.

Just change the signature so it uses reference:

```
void crashSystem(int *&dynamicArray, int asize)
```

and it should work fine.

Comment: Wow! It really works now, thank you. Can't believe solution was so easy.

Comment: that was only for testing purposes, I normally use <vector> all the time