# Dynamically allocating arrays of structs in c++. Why is the array getting overwritten?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-management, dynamic, struct

So for an assignment at school, I have to dynamically allocate arrays of struct Pieces then fill the array with code from a .txt file. It seems to go just fine, but whenever I check after filling the array, it only ever states the last element. If I try to check any specific element or if I try incrementing, it crashes. I have poured over this code and I can't figure out what is wrong...please help

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

struct Pieces
{
    char* word;
    int jump;
};

void reset(char*, int);
int strLen(char*);
void createArr(char*, char*);

int main()
{
    char* temp;
    int numWords;
    int numKeys;
    int count = 0;
    Pieces* cipher;
    Pieces* resett;
    ifstream input;

    temp = new char[20];
    input.open("Project4Data.txt");
    input >> numWords;
    input >> numKeys;
    cipher = new Pieces[numWords];
    resett = cipher;

    while(input >> temp)
    {
        createArr(cipher->word, temp);
        cipher->word = temp;
        //cout << cipher->word << " ";
        input >> cipher->jump;
        //cout << cipher->jump << endl;
        count++;
        if(count == numWords)
            break;
        cipher++;
        reset(temp, 20);
    }
        input.close();
        cipher = resett;
        cout << *(cipher)->word ;
        delete[] resett;
        delete[] cipher;
        return 0;
}

int strLen(char* word)
{
    int s = 0;
    //cout << word;
    for(int x = 0; *(word + x) != '\0'; x++)
        s++;
    return s;
}

void reset(char* arr, int size)
{
    for(int x = 0; x  < size; x++)
        *(arr + x) = '\0';
}

void createArr(char* a, char* b)
{
    //cout << b << b;
    a = new char[strLen(b)];
}
```

Heres the text file we're supposed to use:

23
11

Java 2 linux 3 fear 0 pool 2 do 0 red 1 lock. 1 I 0 random 2 computers, 0 not 0 the 0 open 2 car! 2 C, 0 lack 0 of 0 dog 1 green 2 C++ 0 bottle 2 wrong, 2 them. 0

Comment: I'll suggest you to run with debugger. The crash happens when dereferncing  invalid `cipher` in the following line: `cout << *(cipher)->word ;`

Comment: `cipher = resett;delete[] resett;delete[] cipher;` see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9169774/what-happens-in-a-double-delete). That's is only one minor part of what's wrong here.

Comment: BTW: Are you suppossed to use C-style char arrays instead of `std::string`?

Comment: Yes, I have to use C-Style strings only