# c++ do I need to manually delete a void* pointer which is then pointing to another concrete type?

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers

Assume I have a pointer `void* p`, then after some passing in and out of functions, let's say p is now pointing to `int`. Then do I need to manually delete as `delete static_cast<int*>(p)`?

In most places people say `delete` only happen when there is `new`. But in this case, it's not but does C++ itself remember to release that memory?

Comment: You only `delete` what you `new`. That always holds!! Stuff with automatic memory will have its memory handled automatically irrelevant of what you cast it to.

Comment: If you don't know where an allocation came from check the documentation for whatever provided it. It may be managed for you and it may require you to call a API function to free it.

Comment: Not all memory in C++ has to be released, both primitive types and objects may be somewhere on the stack, or in the global data section. Having a pointer to something does not mean it needs to be freed.

Comment: I'm worried that this question may encourage bad habits.  A `void*` is rather unusual in C++.  Putting that `void*` in charge of the lifetime of an object is almost certainly a design mistake.

Comment: 'Assume I have a pointer void* p'  There is literally no need for a void* in modern c++; it's a hack to do things that weren't possible in C, which got carried over, but in all modern c++ code, even if it interacts with C, shouldn't use them.  Your assumption is rejected ;)

Comment: @DrewDormann Now we have Modern C++ and smart pointers calling `new` and `delete` is (usually) a bad habit!

Comment: @UKMonkey: Win32 programming frequently uses `void *`. Legacy code is everywhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That all depends on how the `int` you're pointing to was allocated, you only `delete` what you `new`.

---

Correct (the `int` is `new`'d):

```
int* a = new int;
void* p = a;

//somewhere later...

delete static_cast<int*>(p);
```

---

Bad (the `int` is automatically managed):

```
int a = 0;
void* p = &a;

//somewhere later...

delete static_cast<int*>(p);
```

---

Answering the comment code, doing:

```
int* a = new int; 
void* p = a; 

delete p;
```

Is *never* okay. You should never `delete` through a `void*`, it's undefined behavior.

---

side note : in modern C++ you really shouldn't be using `new` or `delete`, stick with smart pointers or standard containers.

Comment: What happens if they write `int* a = new int; void* p = a; delete p;`? Is that safe (and possibly what the OP actually needs to know)?

Comment: @Xirema Deleting a void * is undefined.

Comment: see [Deleting via a void pointer is undefined by the C++ Standard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/941959/)

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is: "It depends".

> In most places people say `delete` only happen when there is `new`.

That's true so far as it goes.  To avoid wasting resources and to ensure all destructors are called correctly every `new` has to be balanced by a `delete` somewhere.  If your code can follow several paths you have to make sure that every path calls `delete` (if calling `delete` is appropriate).

The can get tricky when exceptions are thrown which is one reason why [Modern C++](https://isocpp.org/tour) programmers generally avoid using `new` and `delete`.  Instead they use the smart pointers `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr` along with the helper template functions `std::make_unique<T>` and `std::make_shared<T>` (see the SO question: [What is a smart pointer and when should I use one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106508/what-is-a-smart-pointer-and-when-should-i-use-one)) to implement a technique known as [RAII (Resource Acquisition Is Instantiation)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization).

> But in this case, it's not …

Remember that the phrase *... when there is a `new`* refers to the object the pointer points to **not** the pointer itself.  Consider the following code...

```
int *a = new int();

void *p = a;

if (SomeTest())
{
   delete a;
}
else
{
   a = nullptr;
}

// This line is needed if SomeTest() returned false
// and undefined (dangerous) if SomeTest() returned true
delete static_cast<int *> (p);
```

Is that last line of code needed?

The object that `a` and `p` both point to was created by calling `new` so `delete` has to be called on *something*.  If the function `SomeTest()` returned `false` then `a` has been set to `nullptr` so calling `delete` on it won't affect the object we created.  Which means we *do* need that last line of code to properly delete the object that was newed up in the first line of code.

On the other hand, if the function `SomeTest()` returned `true` then we've already called `delete` for the object via the pointer `a`.  In that case the last line of code is **not** needed and in fact may be dangerous.

The C++ standard says that calling `delete` on an object that has already been deleted results in "undefined behaviour" which means *anything* could happen.  See the SO question: [What happens in a double delete?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9169774/654614)

> does C++ itself remember to release that memory?

Not for anything created by calling `new`.  When you call `new` you are telling the compiler "I've got this, I will release that memory (by calling `delete`) when appropriate".

> do I need to manually delete

Yes: **if the object pointed to needs to be deleted here and the `void *` pointer is the only pointer you can use to `delete` the object**.