# free(): double free detected

Tags: c++, free

I am having trouble with programming this code. I believe that there is no syntax error in my code, yet I am still not getting the desired output.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Shape {
public:
    Shape(int size) : size(size) {
        data = new int[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
            data[i] = i;
        }
    }

    virtual ~Shape() {
        delete[] data;
    }

    virtual void printInfo() const {
        std::cout << "Shape with size " << size << std::endl;
    }

protected:
    int* data;
    int size;
};

class Circle : public Shape {
public:
    Circle(int size, int radius) : Shape(size), radius(radius) {}

    ~Circle() {

        delete[] data;
    }

    void printInfo() const override {
        std::cout << "Circle with size " << size << " and radius " << radius << std::endl;
    }

private:
    int radius;
};

void printShapeInfo(const Shape& shape) {
    shape.printInfo();
}

int main() {
    std::vector<Shape*> shapes;

    shapes.push_back(new Circle(5, 3));
    shapes.push_back(new Shape(7));

    for (const Shape* shape : shapes) {
        printShapeInfo(*shape);
        delete shape;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is the output I am expecting:

```
Circle with size 5 and radius 3
Shape with size 7
```

And this is the output I am receiving:

```
Circle with size 5 and radius 3
free(): double free detected in tcache 2
Aborted
```

Comment: You need to learn about [the rules of three/five/zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). I personally recommend the rule of zero, by switching all your pointers and memory allocation to use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: But that isn't the error in this specific case... The error is that you have two destructors that try to delete the same data. But the solution is still the same: Start using `std::vector`.

Comment: Your code shows a double delete. You try to free data  in ~Shape() and in ~Circle().

Comment: [What happens in a double delete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9169774/what-happens-in-a-double-delete)

Comment: I refere you to the first comment. Master the **rule 350**, before anything.

Comment: `Circle` did not allocate the `data`, so it has no business freeing it. That is `Shape`'s job. Get rid of the `~Circle` destructor.

Comment: Never use child destructor to destroy parent objects. Parent object already does that. Also, if you need a simple automatic delete, don't do it in the destructor. Use smart pointers instead, see this reference for more info
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/smart-pointers-modern-cpp?view=msvc-170

Comment: Fixed your title. Every unexpected execution is a 'semantic error' of some kind, but duplicate free is a very specific error that should have appeared in your title. Be specific.

Answer (score 0):

To fix your code, you can either remove the delete[] data statement from the Circle’s destructor, or define a copy constructor and a copy assignment operator for the Shape class. Here is an example of the latter option:

```
class Shape {
public:
Shape(int size) : size(size) {
    data = new int[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        data[i] = i;
    }
}

// Copy constructor
Shape(const Shape& other) : size(other.size) {
    data = new int[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        data[i] = other.data[i];
    }
}

// Copy assignment operator
Shape& operator=(const Shape& other) {
    if (this != &other) {
        delete[] data;
        size = other.size;
        data = new int[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
            data[i] = other.data[i];
        }
    }
    return *this;
}

virtual ~Shape() {
    delete[] data;
}

virtual void printInfo() const {
    std::cout << "Shape with size " << size << std::endl;
}

protected:
int* data;
int size;
};

class Circle : public Shape {
public:
Circle(int size, int radius) : Shape(size), radius(radius) {}

~Circle() {
    // No need to delete data here, it is done by the base class
}

void printInfo() const override {
    std::cout << "Circle with size " << size << " and radius " << radius << 
std::endl;
}

private:
int radius;
};

void printShapeInfo(const Shape& shape) {
shape.printInfo();
}

int main() {
std::vector<Shape*> shapes;

shapes.push_back(new Circle(5, 3));
shapes.push_back(new Shape(7));

for (const Shape* shape : shapes) {
    printShapeInfo(*shape);
    delete shape;
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: @jabaa No, when Circle is deleted, its destructor will be called, and after that, Shapes destructor will be called, where data will be deleted. This is precisely why the double deletion error occours in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with how you delete the objects in the main function. Because you're using polymorphism, you should specify the vector to carry Shape pointers rather than Shape* pointers. This is the correct code:

1.Base Class Shape:

```
 class Shape {
    public:
        Shape(int size) : size(size) {
            data = new int[size];
            for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
                data[i] = i;
            }
        }
    
    
        virtual ~Shape() {
            delete[] data;
        }
    
        virtual void printInfo() const {
            std::cout << "Shape with size " << size << std::endl;
        }

protected:
    int* data;
    int size;
};
```

This is the base class Shape. It has a constructor that initializes a dynamically allocated array data with values from 0 to size-1. The destructor takes care of freeing the memory allocated for data. The printInfo function is declared as virtual, making it polymorphic.

2. Derived Class Circle:

```
class Circle : public Shape {

    public:
    
        Circle(int size, int radius) : Shape(size), radius(radius) {}
    
    
        void printInfo() const override {
            std::cout << "Circle with size " << size << " and radius " << radius << std::endl;
        }
    
    private:
        int radius;
};
```

This is the derived class Circle that inherits from the Shape class. It has its own constructor that initializes the base class and sets the radius. The destructor is implicitly calling the base class destructor. The printInfo function is overridden to provide specific information about the circle.

3. printShapeInfo Function:

```
void printShapeInfo(const Shape& shape) {
    shape.printInfo();
}
```

This function takes a reference to a Shape object and calls its printInfo function. It is designed to work with polymorphism, allowing it to print information about any derived class object that is passed to it.

4. main Function:

```
int main() {
    std::vector<Shape*> shapes;


    shapes.push_back(new Circle(5, 3));
    shapes.push_back(new Shape(7));

 
    for (const Shape* shape : shapes) {
        printShapeInfo(*shape);
        delete shape; // Delete each dynamically allocated object
    }

    return 0;
}
```

In the main function, a vector of pointers to Shape objects is created. A Circle object and a Shape object are dynamically allocated and their pointers are added to the vector. Then, a loop iterates through the vector, calling printShapeInfo for each shape and deleting the dynamically allocated objects